# How do I dock a wing?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

In X3AP, it doesn't seem possible to order a wing to dock. The ships will just orbit the chosen station but not dock. Is there a way to dock a wing without dismantling the wing first.

Comment: Does the station the wing is docking at have enough small fighter ports?  Only certain stations can dock unlimited fighters (most trade stations, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you order a wing to dock at a station, it will attempt to do so unless there are not enough docking slots available for all ships in your wing.  This is usually only an issue on smaller stations that only have external docking ports or if your wing consists of ships other than fighters.

If you order a wing of fighters to dock at a station (such as a trade port) or a carrier with enough hangar capacity that has a hangar bay, then the entire wing should be able to dock with no problems.

Comment: I attempted to dock a wing of 4 fighters at Terracorp HQ, which should be fine in that case (although there are a dozen or so ships already docked there-- I will try to dock them at another station and report back.

Comment: @Jack If can still see the ship after they dock, then its an external docking port (I believe Terracorp only has external ports).  If you see fighters enter a hangar type structure and disappear after docking, then that means the station has an internal port and can hold unlimited fighters.

Comment: OK it appears that Terracorp was indeed at capacity.